# PHP preg_replace skipping where match overlaps

Tags: php, regex

I've been Googling this regex behavior all afternoon.

```
$str = ' b c d w i e f g h this string';

echo preg_replace('/\s[bcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]{1}\s/', ' ', $str);
```

I want to remove all instances of a single character by itself (except for A and I) and leave one space in its place. This code appears to work on every other match. I suspect this is because the matches overlap each other.

I suspect a lookaround would be appropriate here, but I've never used them before and could use a snippet.

EDIT:
Just to avoid confusion about what I am trying to accomplish. I want to turn the above string into this:

```
$str = ' i this string';
```

Notice all single-letter characters that are NOT "A" or "I" have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/(?<=\s)[b-hj-zB-HJ-Z](?=\s)/
```

or modify the ranges if you dont need both `i` and `I`.

Comment: Excellent. That is just what I expected and your example works exactly as I needed.

Comment: @Tanoro: do you have any H letter in your alphabet?

Comment: @Tanoro This also ignores `h` or `H`.

Comment: @RohitJain: I am not sure that Tanoro take the time to read comments as he doesn't take the time to read answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *look-arounds* instead. They are 0-length matches, and hence would not consume spaces. And `{1}` is really absurd there, you can remove it.

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\s)[bcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ](?=\s)/', '', $str)
```

You can make use of *range* and case-insensitive flag `(?i)` here, to reduce the pain of typing all those characters:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?i)(?<=\s)[B-HJ-Z](?=\s)/', '', $str)
```

or word boundaries will also work here:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?i)\b[B-HJ-Z]\b/', '', $str)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ranges. You misunderstood what I am trying to accomplish. The only single-letter words in English are "a" and "I". These are permitted in the string. Any other letters sitting by themselves need to be stripped out. Your solution strips EVERYTHING out except I's and A's.

Comment: @Tanoro. Ok. You can use look arounds then. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
echo preg_replace('~(?i)\b[B-HJ-Z]\b~', ' ', $str);
```

Notice: instead of using spaces to delimit the single letter, I use word boundaries which are the zero width limit between a character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and another character. This is more general than a space and include (for example) punctuation symbols.

Comment: I resent your implication above that I don't read answers. I was inappropriate. As for your solution, it is unnecessary in the specific project in which I was working. The string would not have contained punctuation symbols, so delimiting by space sufficed just fine.